# Does rand() / RAND_MAX return[0, 1) or [0,1]?

Tags: c, random

I have looked at many places and cannot seem to find the answer. I understand that the probability of `rand() / RAND_MAX == 1` is low because `rand()` is unlikely to equal `RAND_MAX`.
However is it theoretically possible?
I saw someone write, on something similar, that the range is `[0, 1)`, however I do not understand why.

Thanks!

Comment: This is integer division as written. Making it floating point division opens other cans of worms though...

Comment: [c++reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) says the upper bound is included.

Comment: I have added the '(double) rand() / RAND_MAX' to clarify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bizarrely `rand() / RAND_MAX` will *only* draw 0 or 1 due to the effects of *integer division*.

Did you mean `1.0 * rand() / RAND_MAX`? That *can* draw 0 and 1; the reason being that `rand()` is allowed to return `RAND_MAX`.

That's an unusual way of having things. Normally you don't want to draw 1, so quite often you'll see

```
rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)
```

instead. Note that the `1.0` forces the denominator to assume a floating point type, and the numerator will also therefore be promoted. On its own, `RAND_MAX + 1` is liable to overflow an integral type, which could have undefined results.

Comment: Well... unless you want to have an *extremely* biased coin simulation.

Comment: I have edited to clarify. The code was `(double) rand() / RAND_MAX`.

Comment: @dng: I'd be inclined to roll it back: it doesn't really add anything to the question, and it invalidates this and the other answer.

Comment: So how do you take a `rand()` result and convert it to, say, a 6-sided die value of 1 to 6? If it can return 0, and it can return 1, then that's quite difficult.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand

> Returns a pseudo-random integer value between ​0​ and RAND_MAX (0 and RAND_MAX included).

Quoting from standard:
http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22
(bold by me)

> RAND_MAX
>   which expands to an integer constant expression that is the **maximum value returned** by the rand function

Those quotes show that `RAND_MAX` **can** be returned, but as you say, very unlikely.

For `rand() / RAND_MAX` it means that 1 is actually a possible result, though because of integer division, 0 is the only other possible result.

However, if you calculate in floating points, in order to aslo get the values in between, then be careful with the problems described here:
[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)